# Need help in registration system

Tags: laravel

In  laravel9 I have created following tables

- users (its laravel auth ui)
- tournamnets
- matches (in matches i have column "name")
- registrations (in registration I have relation with users and one column status_id Bydefault its 0  and relation with matches is hasmany and belongsTo)

Note: match id is linked with hasmany and belongsto relation
Note: registrations and tournamnets have Pivot table which is reg_tours

Column names are `tournaments_id` and `registrations_id`.

Now I need with user  registered for the specific tournament and registrations status is 0 the show {you are registered} in that specific tournament  and if with user  registered for the specific tournament and that registrations status is any match id which is linked with belongs to relation then show that match name

Tournament Controller

```
public function singleTournament($id) {
   $game = Game::all();
   $data = Tournament::find($id);

   if ($data->teamsize == 1) {
      $data->teamsize = "Solo";
   } elseif ($data->teamsize == 2) {
      $data->teamsize = "Duo";
   } elseif ($data->teamsize == 4) {
      $data->teamsize = "Squad";
   }
   return view('site.tournament',compact('data','game'));
}
```

Thank You!

I need to show status for specific tournament to specific user

Comment: have you tried making mysql query using your favorite mysql tool like phpmyadmin ?

Comment: No. I'm newbie I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can add initialize for the status variable before

Comment: what does it mean???